# CSS Animation Image loading when page loads

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have been trying to add CSS Sliding Animation in website. The problem I am facing is, when I made this script live the image gets loaded in the website first and after sometime the animation starts.

I want only the animation to start in the website when the page loads.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/be6enbvq/)

html:

```
<div id="slide1" style="position:absolute">
  <img src="http://rilwis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/5.jpg">
</div>
```

css:

```
<style>
  @-webkit-keyframes slidingstep1 {
    0%   { left: -100px; opacity:0;}
    5%   { left: -75px; opacity:0.2;}
    10%   { left: -50px; opacity:0.4;}
    15%   { left: -25px; opacity:0.6;}    
    20%  { left: 0px;opacity:1; }
    100% { left: 0px;opacity:1; }
  }

  #slide1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: slidingstep1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;         
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: So, you want to start the animation before the page is loaded? If the image hasn't been loaded yet, you won't see anything anyway. Or do you want to hide the image until the animation starts?

Answer (score 1):

**I think your observation isn't fully correct.**

You say that the page loads and the animation happens later. But what I see is something different:

1. Page loads, animation starts immediately
2. After 20% of the animation (2 seconds), no changes happen anymore; the image stands still
3. After 10 seconds, the animation is over and starts over again, because you set `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Maybe you did't see the first part of the animation, maybe because your browser was still loading.

However, to prevent repetition, just set

```
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

On top of that, you may want to prevent a 10s-animation that does nothing for 8 seconds, but just use a 2s-animation in the first place:

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/be6enbvq/1/) *(works on Firefox)*

Comment: Additionally you can smoothen the animation by using a 3D translation: https://jsfiddle.net/be6enbvq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$(window).load(function() {}` function

```js
$(window).load(function() {      
  $("#slide1").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

```css
@keyframes slidingstep1 {
 0%   { left: -100px; opacity:0;}
 5%   { left: -75px; opacity:0.2;}
 10%   { left: -50px; opacity:0.4;}
 15%   { left: -25px; opacity:0.6;}    
 20%  { left: 0px;opacity:1; }
 100% { left: 0px;opacity:1; }
}
#slide1 {
 animation-name: slidingstep1;
 animation-duration: 10s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;         
 animation-direction: normal;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide1" style="position:absolute"><img src="http://rilwis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/5.jpg"></div>
```